# Advantage of cache layer on top of high-performance read model (database)

Tags: azure, caching, redis, azure-table-storage

I'm currently watching and studying several software architecture techniques that exists and that you can take into account when developing hyper-scale applications. Web-scale architecture, as they say.

I've now learned that you can split your read and write model/database. So now I build a Data layer in my application that writes to a RDBMS (SQL SERVER) but reads from Azure Table Storage (which is super fast when properly partitioned).

The question is, why would or should I add a layer of caching (for example a distributed Redis cache) on top of the read model when it's already super fast? What the performance to gain/advantages? If I understand correctly, it only adds another layer of complexity because you have to deal with stale data.

Answer (score 2):

A caching layer is always going to be faster and be able to handle higher throughput than a RDBMS with all else equal.

Basically, you can do more complicated, but slower queries against your RDBMS, and then store them in your caching layer, which is basically just a key-value store for O(1) access. In contrast, basically no queries against your RDBMS will be that fast. If you have a lot of people hitting the same queries repeatedly, this is a good path to both scaling and giving your users a faster experience.

Yes, the trade-off is it adds an extra layer of complexity. If your database is strong and fast enough to handle current load+, don't worry about caching. If, on the other hand, you are trying to scale or give your users a faster experience, caching is much less complex than sharding or clustering your database, and for many applications will go farther and require less implementation and maintenance work.

Comment: I know that a cache is way faster than a RDBMS, but I already have a NoSQL data store that acts as a fast read model (I don't query my RDBMS, it's only for writing and to ensure data consistency). I don't know if caching is still relevant in such an architecture. Do you understand what I mean?